# Laravel 5 Session_driver database token mismatch

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session, laravel-5

I wanted to store all sessions in the database instead of files. But when i do this the csrf tokens refresh after every request.

**View:**

```
Session: kKo5xTIRTC2s6ddvSDUOUqhnji9gLXHp058leP2w
Form: kKo5xTIRTC2s6ddvSDUOUqhnji9gLXHp058leP2w
```

**VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
Session: RYBIUV8R2SjwuOARdRl4s5EY4vpRPMQ1JLGMnqFd
Form: kKo5xTIRTC2s6ddvSDUOUqhnji9gLXHp058leP2w
```

Note that the problem is solved if i switch back to session_driver: file.

**These fields are in table 'sessions':**

```
id,
user_id,
ip_address,
user_agent,payload,last_activity
```

If you guys have any suggestions please post it here ^^.
Other threads did not have the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Found my mistake.

I made the ID column in the table a integer with Auto Increment. While this should be a varchar(100) with unique.